Generating Report For a Server Project in Magic Draw Using Command Line
I am trying to generate a report for a server project in Magic Draw using the command line but am not able to do so. The command line works perfectly for a local project and the report generates without any issue, but when I try to do the same for a server project, it gives me the following error

Connecting to Teamwork Cloud... Error: Unable to login into Teamwork
Cloud  with user  Please make sure the given
login name and password is correct and you already logout from all
other client with the same login name.

My credentials are correct for the user account I am using, as I am able to login into Teamwork Cloud manually when I connect to my server project in Magic Draw. And I have tried logging out from all other client but still it fails on the command line.
I thought my user account might have permissions issue but even the admin account fails to log in
The support ticket I generated didn't help much and the last thing they replied was "to add a certificate in Magic Draw" without any explanation on how to generate it and where to add it.
Anyone out there who has done the same or know how can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance

I had this same issue and this is how I solved it:
I started with accessing the hidden file in your root directory called 'ProgramData'. From there, go to .DESE/X.X.X and copy the 'certs' file.
Navigate to your AppData hidden folder in your current user directory. From there go to Local/.magic.systems.of.systems.architect/2021x and paste the certs file to this directory.
Run your generate script again and it should work.
